# Elasticsearch / Kibana: Subtraction across pre-aggregated time-series data

Tags: elasticsearch, data-science, kibana, elastic-stack

I am working with Johns Hopkins University CSSE COVID19 data, published on [their GitHub](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19).  Some of the metrics they publish in their daily US reports are sum aggregations.  I would like to perform basic math against the values within a given field so that I can get a daily tally.

JHU publishes their data daily, so let's assume that the numbers reported reflect a 24-hour period.

Example: In the State of New York, I can see the following values for `Last_Update` and `Recovered`, where `Recovered` is a rolling sum of all cases where people have recovered from infection:

```
Last_Update,Recovered    
2020-08-05,73326
2020-08-04,73279
2020-08-03,73222
2020-08-02,73134
2020-08-01,73055
2020-07-31,72973
```

Ideally, I would like to create a new field (be it a scripted field, or a new field that is generated via a Logstash Filter processor) called `RecoveredToday`, where the field value reflects the difference between today's `Recovered` aggregation and yesterday's `Recovered` aggregation.

```
Last_Update,Recovered,RecoveredToday    
2020-08-05,73326,47
2020-08-04,73279,57
2020-08-03,73222,88
2020-08-02,73134,79
2020-08-01,73055,82
2020-07-31,72973,...
```

In the above data set, `RecoveredToday` is calculated from the value of `Recovered` on `2020-08-05` minus the value of `Recovered` on `2020-08-04`.

```
73326 - 73279 = 47
```

With respect to using a Scripted Field in Kibana, according to [this blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields), Scripted Fields can only analyze fields within one given document at a time, and cannot perform calculations against a field across multiple documents.

I do see user @agung-darmanto [solved a similar problem on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053482/subtract-numeric-fields-between-two-documents-with-different-timestamp/), but the solution calls out specific dates rather than performing rolling calculations.  It's also unclear from the code snippet if the results are being inserted into a new field that can subsequently be used to build visualizations.

The approach to use Logstash ruby processing on the fly also presents a problem.  Logstash, as far as I know, cannot access an already ingested document ... and if it can, it's probably a pretty ugly superpower to wield.

Goal: There are other fields provided in the JHU CSSE data which are also pre-aggregated.  I would like to produce visualizations that reflect trends such as:

- Number of new cases per day
- Number of new hospitalizations per day
- Number of new deaths per day

Using the data they provide, I can build visualizations that will plateau, and that plateau reflects a reduction of incidences.  I'm trying to produce visualizations that show ZERO.